# Launch dialog on uninstall using WiX

Tags: wix

I have created a WiX installer and would like to launch a custom action dialog on uninstall. From this dialog I would like to gather information on why the user is uninstalling my application (well, this means just launching the web-browser).

I have seen some people using the `On="uninstall"` property, but I am not sure if this is the one to use, and how to use it, for the above action.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819686/wix-open-web-page-when-uninstall-completes

Comment: Hey Thanks!
Strange, I did not find this one when searching...

Comment: Hmmm. I still can't quite figure out how to add a dialog on exit. Launching the browser should eventually be optional, some people might not want to give us feedback. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows doesn't show UI when a product is uninstalled from Add/Remove Programs or Programs and Features.

Comment: Hi thanks. I just realized this myself, so I will make a little feedback app. that is launched when my program is uninstalled. Now just to figure out, how to halt the uninstall process until the user has pressed a button on the feedback app.?

Answer (score 1):

JakobJ: I wouldn't mess with this uninstall sequence. Any modal dialog that pops up when the installation is run in silent mode (which it is from add/remove) could cause your entire product to be axed in a corporate environment. If your uninstall is invoked from a management system such as SCCM and the uninstall on a lot of machines fails because the uninstall gets stuck on a dialog, this will not soon be forgotten. Trust me.