# Wix Open Page without using WixUtilExtension

Tags: wix, wix-extension

I followed the solution on [Wix Open web page when uninstall completes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819686/wix-open-web-page-when-uninstall-completes)

It works but I want to modify the solution so that I don't have to put -ext WixUtilExtension when use light.exe

```
<Property Id="MyURL"><![CDATA[http://www.myurl.com/]]></Property>
<CustomAction Id="SetOpenURL" Property="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[MyURL]" />
<Binary Id="WixCA" SourceFile="C:\LocationOfFile\WixUtilExtension.dll" /> 
<CustomAction Id="OpenURL" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixShellExec" Impersonate="yes" Return="ignore" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <!-- Launch webpage during full uninstall, but not upgrade -->
    <Custom Action="SetOpenURL" After="InstallFinalize"></Custom>
    <Custom Action="OpenURL" After="SetOpenURL"></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

however, this solution does not work. Can someone please explain to me why?

Comment: WixUtilExtension.dll is a WiX extension, not a custom action DLL. Why are you trying to avoid using the extension the "normal" way?

Comment: Why do you have this strange requirement? What's the problem with `-ext WixUtilExtension`?